# Last Android update removed icons from several apps

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g3

I have a Moto G 3rd generation, and updated it with latest Android version (24.11.25). After the Update the icons for some APP disappeared.

I think it were all the applications i had moved to my SD card.

The APP is not showing on my desktop neither on the menu that shows all applications, but its still installed, because i can open the APP from its page on play store and it is on the list of installed applications on the config page. 
How can i restore the icons to these apps?

Comment: From play store page can you try to uninstall an app and reinstall? If it installs, then the icon should appear...clumsy approach. Alternatively can you try moving one app back to internal storage to see if icon reappears?

Comment: @beeshyams the latter approach is to be preferred, as with the former the app's data would be lost. // Could indeed be an issue with App2SD (that's what you've used I assume?). This sometimes happens on device startup, especially with "slower" cards (cards are mounted *after* the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, i.e. at the same time the launcher is started; so if the launcher was faster and the mount to slow, the launcher doesn't see those apps as available. A reload of the launcher app should solve that then as well).

Answer (score 0):

Go into Applications, click on the app affected, force stop, then select the storage, then click change. Force stop may restore the icons, but if you prefer you can move the apps back to internal for safety.

Answer (score 0):

Download All-in-one Toolbox from the Google Play store and when entering the app go to the toolbox option (it's on the right side) and then tap app2sd and have it scan your SD card. Voilà! All of your apps shall appear.